# Configure/ Set YouTube Subtitles/ Close Captions CC to Auto-Translate to English permanently? How?

Tags: youtube, subtitles, translation

Configure/ Set YouTube Subtitles/ Close Captions CC to Auto-Translate to English permanently? How?

Every time I open a video on YouTube (especially if it is not in English) I have to go through multiple clicks in the Settings menu through Auto Translate to English to make this happen.

Is there no way to configure / set it & forget it permanently?